# how to check php variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

i want check if variable inside php is have active value
i test like this but not work

i have this var inside check.php

```
$status = 'active';
```

and i have this inside javascript file

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        success: function(check) {
        var statusJS = '<?php echo $status; ?>';
        if (check[statusJS] == "active" {
        alert("status : active");
}}})
```

this full check.php file

```
<?php
$status = 'active';
$gpa = 'html data here';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
echo $gpa;
echo $status;
} else {
include("gp-e.php");
}
?>
```

it is possible to get variable value from php in javascript without echo it in php file ?

Comment: check `var_dump($status)` and `console.log(check,check[statusJs])`

Comment: really i not understand exactly where i'll put this in php or in javascript but i test it in javascript but get undefined in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<?php
$status = 'active';
$gpa = 'html data here';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ($status == 'active') {
        return print_r($status);
    }

} else {
include("gp-e.php");
}
?>

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"dt.php",
    success:function(data){
        //alert(data);
        if (data.trim() == 'active') 
        {
            alert("status:" + data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Status:Inactive");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but where echo $gpa, and i want check php variable from javascript but maybe that is impossible to do, so thank you anyway :D, and if you are interested about my (idea), i want protect my script from stolen by httrack etc, so i want make js check if variable have same value in php file, but the thief can't get variable value because download files only as html so can't get my script to run :D

Answer (score 0):

No as per me,It is not possible to get variable value from php without echo in javascript.

But u can assign php value in one of input field and get its value in javascript.

Like below code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>" />
```

Now to get that value in javascript ::

```
var status = $("#status").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `echo` it in `check.php` and create an array

```
$status = 'active';
$gpa = 'some string'
$data = $status . ',' . $gpa
echo $data
```

and in your javascript

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check.php",
        success: function(data) {
        var check = (new Function("return [" + data + "];")());
        if (check[0] == "active") { // check[0] is $status in php
        alert("status : active");
}}})
```

*if you want to `echo` multiple values. you can create an object/array.

Comment: after echo it in php how i can get in javascript after echo ?

Comment: just directly compare it like the answer

Comment: i have more data inside php file, how i can check only status variable ?

Comment: what is the data structure ? php array? php object?

Comment: only html data.

Comment: can u give me the example what is in the php? something more detail than the current question.

Comment: i'm add full php file, check it

Comment: not work for me but,anyway thank you for help, my idea did not go the right way, because i want only get variable value from php without echo it, (to protect my script from stolen with httrack etc) (i want make js check if php file give value from variable without echo it, so anyone stolen my script can't get it to work because js not find variable value) maybe you understand what i want to do :D

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
<?php
  $status = 'active';
  $gpa = 'html data here';

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

     $response = [
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $gpa
     ];

     echo json_encode($response);

   } else {
       include("gp-e.php");
   }
 ?>
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        if (data['status'] == "active" {
            alert("status : active");
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: my php file not all inside it is json so maybe will not work, i'll test it

Comment: can you add your php file full code so we can help. or you can create one function for check status in check.php file

Comment: my php file is very simple, i'm added, check it

Comment: it's work, but another functions broken because add datatype:json now script can't get html from php, lol, anyway thank you for help, my idea did not go the right way, because i want only get variable value from php without echo it, (to protect my script from stolen with httrack etc) (i want make js check if php file give value from variable without echo it, so anyone stolen my script can't get it to work because js not find variable value) maybe you understand what i want to do :D

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to check if the `$status = 'active'` and return the html data to your javascript?

Comment: yes but without print it in browser, i want only check it in js